# Events and polymorphic design

Tags: c#, events, interface, delegates, polymorphism

In a typical RPG setting, I'm trying to make an event design that could handle additional effects from characters abilities.

My main issue is to make such system polymorphic so I can add any effect I want without struggling with argument or return types problems.

Here is an exemple of what I have done so far :

```
public abstract class Character
{
    public int CurrentMP { get; set; }
    public List<ISkill> Moveset { get; protected set; }
    // the rest doesn't matter i guess
}

public interface ISkill
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Weaponskill : ISkill
{
    public int Potency { get; protected set; }
    public IEffects AdditionalEffect { get; set; }
}

public class Warrior : Character
{
    public Warrior ()
    {
        Moveset = new List<Move.ISkill>()
        { 
            new Weaponskill("Sword Slash", 100, new ManaGain(this, 707))
        }
    }
}
```

In another namespace, the events.

```
namespace Additional_Effects 
{
    public delegate void EffectEventHandler(Character character, int gain); 

    public interface IEffects
    {
          event EffectEventHandler Event;
    }

    public class ManaGain : IEffects
    {
        public ManaGain(Character character, int gain)
        {
            Event += OnEffect;
        }

        public event EffectEventHandler Event;

        protected virtual void OnEffect(Character character, int gain)
        {
            character.CurrentMP += gain;
        }

        public void Execute(Character character, int gain)
        {
            if (Event != null)
                Event(character, gain);
        }
    }
}
```

My main problem is that the delegate's argument type and number, and its return type, aren't flexible. I may need a delegate with a completely different definition for another `IEffects` implementation. How can I change my event system to achieve that ?

Moreover, in the case of the `IEffects` implementation I made as an example, I'm not sure if the property `CurrentMP` is actually modified outside of the method, I have a doubt about passing parameters by value or reference here.

Finally I think I can't call my Execute method from my `Weaponskill` class because it knows `IEffect` but not its concrete implementation, but I can't have an Execute method in the interface because I would have to implement it everywhere even if parameters needs may vary in every concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For the delegates, maybe you could use different signature like here: [C# - Is it possible to have multiple method signatures for an Action<>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328243/c-sharp-is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-method-signatures-for-an-action)

If I remember well, in C#, only the object derived from Valuetype are passed by value. You can pass them by reference with the keyword ref if you want. But i don't think it's the case for character.

Currenly, you can't call the execute from the IEffect because Execute is a function of Managain. You have to code the signature of execute and every function you want to be able to call from a IEffect.

Comment: So my character property is actually updated ? Great then. I'm aware that i can't call Execute from IEffect but I also don't want to implement in every child class an execute usefull for one among them only.

I'm looking at your link right now, it looks promising at first sight

Comment: I don't think there is other way for the IEffect. you can work with inheritance too like that only the mother class will have  the function and you can still override it in some child class if you want. But if you don't want to implement a function in every class, interface is not a good way to work